# How to write a summation in Coq

Tags: coq

I have just started getting acquainted with Coq and I would like to write this sum on it:

$\sum_{p=1}^{n} \frac{\mathrm{d}^p}{\mathrm{d}x^p} f(x)$

This is what I have tried:

```ml
Require Import Coquelicot.Coquelicot.

Require Import Coq.Sets.Finite_sets.

Require Import Coq.Reals.Reals.

Section test.

Local Open Scope R_scope.

Variable f : R -> R.

Definition f_p (m : nat)(x : R) := Derive_n f m x.

Local Open Scope nat_scope.

Definition summation_range (n : nat) := sum (fin_range n)(fun p => (Derive_n p f)).
```

The `summation_range` definition yields an error "The reference fin_range was not found
in the current environment". Even though I have just imported the package `Require Import Coq.Sets.Finite_sets.`, which should have `fin_range` on it (according to ChatGPT).

What is the proper way to write it?

Comment: I guess that ChatGPT confused about Coq and Lean. The function `fin_range` is available in Lean: https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/data/list/range.html#list.fin_range

Comment: Horrifying that you'd use ChatGPT to generate code (If I read this correctly). Probably this is something we'll have to discuss as a community if it becomes an issue, but I'd rather you say directly that you need help defining a specific function rather than generate something with ChatGPT and expect us to debug it for you. On another note you might be better off using [sum_f](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Reals.Rfunctions.html#sum_f) rather than finite sets.

Answer (score 0):

There is not such a thing as a single way to talk about sums in Coq, as there are many different libraries with many different purposes in the ecosystem. They will also most likely have different versions of summation.

Still, it seems like you (or ChatGPT ?) are wanting to use Coquelicot, in which case the various summation operators are to be found [here](http://coquelicot.saclay.inria.fr/html/Coquelicot.Hierarchy.html#Sums). There is in particular a [lemma](http://coquelicot.saclay.inria.fr/html/Coquelicot.Hierarchy.html#sum_n_Reals) relating them to the summation on reals from the standard library. You can probably look at [the formalization of series](http://coquelicot.saclay.inria.fr/html/Coquelicot.Series.html#) to see how summation is manipulated.